# Mouseenter event on img inside div works sporadically/erratically

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouseover, image-gallery, mouseenter

I have a grid of thumbnails. Upon hover I'd like to enlarge the images in the center of the screen. Classic, right?

Each thumbnail is wrapped in a div. When I apply a mouseenter or mouseover event on the img or the div, it simply doesn't work so nicely. I hover with the mouse, and some of the thumbnails enlarge, some don't at all, some need a second or third hover, some flicker.

What's going on? Are the thumbnails maybe "hiding" behind something, therefore not seeing the mouse pointer? Does it have to do with the images being inside divs? (I tried to apply the event listeners to either the imgs or divs, in vain).

```html
<div id="editGrid">
   <div> <img src="Gallery1.png" alt=""> </div>
   <div> <img src="Gallery2.png" alt=""> </div>
   <div> <img src="Gallery3.png" alt=""> </div>
</div>
```

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('#editGrid > div')
const images = document.querySelectorAll('#editGrid > div > img')
const bigImageArea = document.querySelector('#edit')
let bigImage

divs.forEach((image, i) => {
    image.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        bigImage = images[i].cloneNode(false)
        bigImage.style.position = 'fixed'
        bigImage.style.left = '50vw'
        bigImage.style.top = '50vh'
        bigImage.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
        bigImageArea.appendChild(bigImage)
    })
    image.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        bigImageArea.removeChild(bigImage)
    })
})
```

Comment: Usually it's an issue of waiting for the img to load, but probably not here. Cloning the node seems inefficient, as does having both mouseenter and mouseleave handlers. Consider putting an img element in the #edit element and just change the src depending on the thumbnail it's over.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But isn't mouseenter/mouseleave standard practice? That asked, I do see how your method would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your `#edit` element overlaps the images and triggers `mouseleave` event. You can disable mouse events on that element with `pointer-events: none;`, also avoid inline styles:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('#editGrid > div')
const images = document.querySelectorAll('#editGrid > div > img')
const bigImageArea = document.querySelector('#edit')
let bigImage

divs.forEach((image, i) => {
  image.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    bigImage = images[i].cloneNode(false)
    bigImageArea.appendChild(bigImage)
  })
  image.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    bigImageArea.removeChild(bigImage)
  })
})
```

```css
#edit
{
  pointer-events: none;
}

#edit > img
{
  position: fixed;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#editGrid > div
{
  width: 30%;
}
#editGrid img
{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="editGrid">
  <div><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/taykG37GWDgY-FGkdogDvsHSJMUGRMvkuVRT6yR-5UNkKvGRKeRlpGYXlslocOcS0txlfUdGW59JGtzADknxbMqnh6AtVCv9EXyB8nHp80YsRNA0Yw=w512-h342-n-l50-sg-rj" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/fl-GT6w3Ls6RT4vYnbkuYUyLY3lZJH8VtZ7xzxiym9YYaoVRCnZehdz6Icd0oAf6i3H9-O5cCNs6eunlxWr_Csstgsb98DdzNdLFBOlhw9NUfHdyuQjI=w384-h512-n-l50-sg-rj" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9pPCK70Rw0k3wethMHb1qMaIB0VjeWLy57vYgSzKbF7oJuvO2nA0Nakk-95cvibWUDcEhYkfCKvdPKT03tXZd4M5jdhIEibLO9qw-XE=w512-h342-n-l50-sg-rj" alt=""></div>
</div>
<div id="edit"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Is assigning styles through JS less efficient? Or is it just a stylistic thing?

Comment: It's harder to customize, takes more space and less efficient.